# Аномальное исчезновение меток yandex map js

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На гите только та часть кода, которая затрагивает yandex карту --
[сылка на гит](https://github.com/krasmag/yandexmapjs/blob/main/main.js)

Аномально исчезают метки в Москве, весь код перешерстил и удалил все кроме добавление в objectManager всех маркеров. У маркеров id уникальные.

mapZoom = 12

[image: mapZoom = 12]

mapZoom = 11

[image: mapZoom = 11]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А минимально работающего примера у вас нет? Создавать проект, встраивать в него ваш элемент кода, подбирать пачку подходящих меток на несколько тысяч объектов... не самая радужная перспектива для желающих проверить, всё ли в порядке тут у Яндекса или у вас.